# How to connect two filters in jquery content? Filter 1 and filter 2 connect result

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm newbie in jquery. I created filters in jquery and i want to connect them together to show content only clicked. How i can do that? Sorry for my bad english. I try many hours and I've building this:

```js
$("button").click(function() {
    var show = $(this).attr('class');
    $('.post').each(function(){
        $(this).show();
        var test = $(this).attr('class');
        if (test.indexOf(show) < 0) $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>FIRST</h2>
<div id='filter'>
    <button class='all'>All</button>
    <button class='1'>One</button>
    <button class='2'>Two</button>
</div>
<h2>TWO</h2>
<div id='filter'>
    <button class='all'>All</button>
    <button class='aa'>Washington</button>
    <button class='bb'>Philadelphia</button>
</div>

<br>
<div id='posts'>
    <div class='all post 1 aa'>One Washington</div>
    <div class='all post 1 bb'>One Philadelphia</div>
    <div class='all post 2 bb'>Two Philadelphia</div>
    <div class='all post 2 aa'>Two Washington</div>
    <div class='all post 1 bb'>One Philadelphia</div>
    <div class='all post 2 aa'>Two Washington</div>
    <div class='all post 1 bb'>One Philadelphia</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Share the source which you tried, and tell us what result you're expecting.

Comment: You are considering each filter in a silo, never together.  That is the crux of your issue.

Comment: Also, you cannot repeat ids.

Comment: I share, sorry my bad edit. I want connect filters. When i click "One" and click "Washinton" I want show only options "One Washington" and no other options. The same when i click Two and Washington or Philadelphia

Comment: Sorry Taplar can i please to fiddle with correct issue for this? I dont understand many things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the comments in the logic for the details on what each step is doing.

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  //remove the selected class from the previously selected button
  $(this).closest('.filter').find('button.selected').removeClass('selected');
  //put the class on the button you clicked
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  
  //get the data-filter off of the selected buttons and join them into a selector
  var filter = '.'+ $('button.selected').map(function(){
    return $(this).data('filter');
  }).get().join('.');
  
  //hide all the posts, and then show those that match
  $('.post').hide().filter(filter).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>FIRST</h2>
<!-- we use a class because an id cannot be repeated
     and we want to select both our filters later -->
<div class='filter'>
    <!-- data fields let us separate the classes from the data that
         is used for the filter -->
    <button data-filter='all'>All</button>
    <button data-filter='1'>One</button>
    <button data-filter='2'>Two</button>
</div>
<h2>TWO</h2>
<div class='filter'>
    <button data-filter='all'>All</button>
    <button data-filter='aa'>Washington</button>
    <button data-filter='bb'>Philadelphia</button>
</div>

<br>
<div id='posts'>
    <div class='all post 1 aa'>One Washington</div>
    <div class='all post 1 bb'>One Philadelphia</div>
    <div class='all post 2 bb'>Two Philadelphia</div>
    <div class='all post 2 aa'>Two Washington</div>
    <div class='all post 1 bb'>One Philadelphia</div>
    <div class='all post 2 aa'>Two Washington</div>
    <div class='all post 1 bb'>One Philadelphia</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow! Great! Big Thank You!

Comment: Can i add hash to this? When i want to url to specyfic filter?

Comment: Sure, you could reference `window.location.hash` as part of building the filter string you use.

Comment: I try...but i dont know what im doing.... can i please my fiddle again sorry? :) for two categories? and for two selected options? for any options this generate hash?

Comment: and can i add to this options selected default? Selected option ONE and Washingtion?

Comment: @obiboke if you are going to change the parameters of your question, you should start another question regarding your new issues.

Comment: I start:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51539259/how-do-i-to-link-to-a-jquery-filtered-view-from-another-page-and-select-default