# How do I to link to a jQuery filtered view from another page and select default filters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Sorry for my knowledge and language. I have two connected filters in jQuery and I want to be able to link from other pages to specific filter views. I know I probably have to use `window.location.hash` but I don't know how.

Second question - How can I add default filters? I want `ONE` and `Washington` as the default selected filters.

Many Thanx for any help

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  //remove the selected class from the previously selected button
  $(this).closest('.filter').find('button.selected').removeClass('selected');
  //put the class on the button you clicked
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  
  //get the data-filter off of the selected buttons and join them into a selector
  var filter = '.'+ $('button.selected').map(function(){
    return $(this).data('filter');
  }).get().join('.');
  
  //hide all the posts, and then show those that match
  $('.post').hide().filter(filter).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>FIRST</h2>
<!-- we use a class because an id cannot be repeated
     and we want to select both our filters later -->
<div class='filter'>
    <!-- data fields let us separate the classes from the data that
         is used for the filter -->
    <button data-filter='all'>All</button>
    <button data-filter='1'>One</button>
    <button data-filter='2'>Two</button>
</div>
<h2>TWO</h2>
<div class='filter'>
    <button data-filter='all'>All</button>
    <button data-filter='aa'>Washington</button>
    <button data-filter='bb'>Philadelphia</button>
</div>

<br>
<div id='posts'>
    <div class='all post 1 aa'>One Washington</div>
    <div class='all post 1 bb'>One Philadelphia</div>
    <div class='all post 2 bb'>Two Philadelphia</div>
    <div class='all post 2 aa'>Two Washington</div>
    <div class='all post 1 bb'>One Philadelphia</div>
    <div class='all post 2 aa'>Two Washington</div>
    <div class='all post 1 bb'>One Philadelphia</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried doing with `window.location.hash`? I see somebody suggested you using it in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51527603/how-to-connect-two-filters-in-jquery-content-filter-1-and-filter-2-connect-resu)

Comment: I'm newbie... i don't know what i'm doing...